# What is the value of $f(x)=−5I_{x>2}(x)+xI_{x<−1}(x)$ when $x=3$?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

What is the value of $f(x)=−5I_{x>2}(x)+xI_{x<−1}(x)$ when $x=3?$
Having trouble working out how to plug value of x = 3 into this indicator function - is it something like $-5 \cdot3 + 3\cdot3$?

Comment: You need to format your posts properly here by using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

> The Indicator function is either $1$ when its condition holds, or $0$, when it does not.

Here you can see that for $x=3$ the first is one and the second is zero. hence the overall result is $-5$.

Comment: Many thanks - answer was really obvious

Answer (score 1):

$ f(x)=−5\mathbb{1}_{x>2}(x)+x\mathbb{1}_{x<−1}(x)$ in $x=3$ is $f(3)=-5$ because $3>2$ and 3 isn't $\leq-1$